# python 3.8, ShareManager, update dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, shared-memory

I have multiple processes and want to use a single GUI to display current data and to send commands to the processes.

I have created a "dataProcess" that provides shared dicts and queues using ShareManager.register(...,...).

The idea is to let a process have its local data but also make some data in the "dataProcess" available to other processes. All local data updates in the processes that are of interest to others are sent in addition to the "dataProcess" through a dataUpdateQueue. The data update messages in the dataUpdateQueue provide the shared dictionary identifyer to be updated and the new data.

My problems start when I try to update the DictProxy objects in the "dataProcess". Updates to my nested dicts get ignored and I can't use the normal sharedDict[key] = changedDict syntax.

I currently circumvent this by having a "shadow" local normal dict in my "dataProcess" (config.sharedDictLocal) with the same structure as the shared dict.

I use the requests for the shared dict update first on my config.sharedDictLocal with a normal dict update command and then assign the config.sharedDictLocal again to the shared DictProxy object.

I am a bit concerned that this is not the right way to do things like that and that in the long run I will encounter problems with my approach (because - if it is so easy to make these shared dicts updatable why is it not implemented like this in the library?).

Comment: Without a code example it's hard to guess but it could be this "If standard (non-proxy) list or dict objects are contained in a referent, modifications to those mutable values will not be propagated through the manager because the proxy has no way of knowing when the values contained within are modified." [Source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list)

Comment: @forgetso Thanks, read that too before. Was not able to find a lot of details how the share manager works and whether it is a good idea to use it as a central data store to be shared by about a dozen processes envolved in my robot control application. Thought also (and tried) an example with redis but that looked to be too big for my usage. I have e.g. a servo control process that receives move commands over a queue and then updates the current and final positions of the servos in the shared memory. Other processes, like the GUI, can than simply display these shared values.

Comment: If you use lists or numpy arrays then you will not run into this issue but you will sacrifice code readability as you will have to refer to the lists by index. If you're list/array shape was static then it would be enough to have a global variable that all processes inherit that contains the indexes to use. You could also just use a database or a file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I once experimented with shared lists but had problems accessing them in my code (find the right syntax?). I am tempted to give it another try as indeed my data could be in lists and indexes could be defined in global Enum's and I do not like these reassignments even when they worked so far for me.